# What are some great resources for mastering Apache administration?

Tags: apache

I've been working with Apache for a couple years now and am comfortable with basic administration and configuration.  However, I'd really like to increase my skill set from basic administration to being a true Apache wizard.  What are some must read books, mailing lists, feeds, etc. for someone looking to increase their overall skill level with Apache?

Comment: +1 this is something I'd really like to know. I've spent plenty of time bashing my head against the wall trying to get Apache configured right and I'm still nowhere near proficient enough to feel comfortable with it.

Comment: I'm trying to post more links, but I need 10 points in reputation to do so.

Answer (score 4):

AskApache:
http://www.askapache.com/

**Edit - more resources:**

HowToForge:
http://www.howtoforge.com/

Comprehensive guide to .htaccess:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

The Definitive Guide to htaccess Techniques: Do’s and Don’ts
http://www.noupe.com/php/htaccess-techniques.html

20 ways to Secure your Apache Configuration:
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/505.cfm

.htaccess Email Group:
http://groups.google.com/group/apachehtaccess?lnk=

alt.apache.configuration Email Group:
http://groups.google.com/group/alt.apache.configuration?lnk=

Comment: +1 Looks like a very informative site.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

[The official Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/) is quite a good place to start.

The documentation seems to have lagged behind the browser, so one tip is to make sure to look at the Apache 1.3 documents, since these are often more complete than the Apache 2.2 ones.

Answer (score 1):

[Stupid htaccess tricks](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/01/10/stupid-htaccess-tricks/), despite the name and colour scheme it's not stupid.